# Capturing Output to a variable for command run over ssh

Tags: ssh, scripting, tcl, expect

I am using the below raw code to initiate connection to a device , run some command and to store the value to a variable 'op' so that I can parse it , But looks like eventhough the commad executed remotely the variable op was not getting set. Also I tried to print the value of expcet buffer but It doesnt have the value of the command o/p . What has gone wrong here ?

```
spawn /usr/bin/ssh root@[lindex $argv 0]
    expect {
      -re ".*Are.*.*yes.*no.*" {
        send "yes\n"
        exp_continue
        #look for the password prompt
      }

      "*?assword:*" {
        send "$password\r"
        expect "#"
        send "\n"
      }

    }

    set op [split [send "$cmd\r"]]
    set op $expect_out(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the below code.

```
set op [split [send "$cmd\r"]]; # 'send' command won't return the 'cmd' output.
```

After sending the command, you have to give the next `expect` statement, then only expect will wait for it and in turn it will be saved into the `expect_out(buffer)`

You have to send the command and wait for the prompt as follows.

```
send "$cmd\r"
expect "#"
puts $expect_out(buffer);  #Will print the output of the 'cmd' output now.
set op [ split $expect_out(buffer) ]
```

This is because without one more `expect` after `send`, we will be missing out what is happening in the spawned ssh session as `expect` will assume that you simply need to send one string value and not expecting anything else from the session.

Remember, usage of `split` without any 2nd argument will lead to split-up of output by `white-space`.

The word to wait for after executing the command, can vary based on your system. It can be `#` or `$` or `>` or `:`; So, make sure you are giving the correct one. Or, you can provide a generalized pattern for the prompt as such

```
set prompt "#|>|:|\\\$"; # We escaped the `$` symbol with backslash to match literal '$'
```

While using the `expect` after sending the commands, it can be used as

```
expect -re $prompt; #Using regex to match the pattern
```

**Update :**

Perhaps, the match of `#` is already available in the expect buffer, thereby leading out to this problem. To avoid this, you can try adding the following line in the code just before sending the commands.

```
expect * 
send "$cmd\r"
expect "#"
puts $expect_out(buffer); #This should have the output of the command executed.
```

> Here the * matches anything. This is like saying, "I don't care what's
>   in the input buffer. Throw it away." This pattern always matches, even
>   if nothing is there. Remember that * matches anything, and the empty
>   string is anything! As a corollary of this behavior, this command
>   always returns immediately. It never waits for new data to arrive. It
>   does not have to since it matches everything.

Comment: Still doesn't work , The expect_out buffer doesn't seem to have the whole output . I tried setting matc_max to 100000 as well but no avail.